# Unsure what this while statement is doing

Tags: c++, while-loop

So, I'm doing homework.  I've encountered something I haven't seen before and cannot find a decent explanation of what it does.  Basically,

```
Object object;
...
while((value1, value2) = function(object)) {
    object.foo(value1, value2);
}
```

The (value1, value2) in the while statement really throws me.  Any ideas?

Comment: You'll find answers by searching for "comma operator". [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54142/1016716)

Comment: Haven't tried.  This was part of a specification.  Not sure what to make of it

Comment: THe others answered what it does.  I just want to comment-  never do this.  Its confusing and brings no value, there's cleaner ways to write it.  This is basically a stupid C++ tricks question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @GabeSechan: I agree with everything you said. But I suspect it may be a failed translation from another language where multiple values can be returned. If the original code has `return 1,2;` inside `function()` one may think that you can call the function like `(a,b) = function();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a comma operator.

The result of the comma operator is the last value (the others are evaluated and discarded).

```
while((value1, value2) = function(object)) {
    object.foo(value1, value2);
}
```

If value1 is just a variable and not an expression then it is equivalent too:

```
while(value2 = function(object)) {
    object.foo(value1, value2);
}
```

If value1 is an expression then it is evaluated each time around the loop. The result is discarded, but if the expression has side effects these will take effect.